# Save all console outputs to a text file

Tags: c#

I'm looking for solutions like a agent or something to capturing all console outputs to a array or text file, which start at the beginning of program.

For example:

```
Main
{

  Start capturing.

  Some operations, functions ect.

  Stop capturing.

}
```

And I want to save all effects of operations and functions to file, like a logs for example.

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried so far? Google is a powerful friend, try taking some things from here to append to an array/list instead of a text box: https://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: `Console.SetOut`

Regarding this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) the below code would Help

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

// First, save the standard output.
var oldConsoleWriter = Console.Out;

using(var stream = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create))
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{  
  Console.SetOut(writer);
  Console.WriteLine("Hello file");
}

Console.SetOut(oldConsoleWriter);
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```